# ng test not passing Jest CLI options any more in v14?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-builder

I am using Jest with Angular (instead of Karma). The `angular.json` file seems to be configured properly, as running `ng test` works.

According to [this article](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-cli-ng-test-with-jest-in-3-minutes-v2-1060ddd7908d):

> You can specify Jest CLI options either in builder options (useful
> when it is a persistent config) or right to `ng test` as a parameter
> (useful when it is a one-timer).
>
> For example to run a single test:
>
> `ng test --testNamePattern="My test suite My test case"`

This was working before my v14 upgrade, but this is not the case any more. Now if I run:

```
ng test --testNamePattern="MyComponent"
```

I get:

```
Error: Unknown argument: testNamePattern
```

```bash
Angular CLI: 14.0.2
Node: 16.13.1
Package Manager: yarn 1.22.17 
OS: darwin arm64

Angular: 14.0.2
... animations, cdk, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core
... elements, forms, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1400.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular   14.0.2
@angular-devkit/core            14.0.2
@angular-devkit/schematics      8.3.29
@schematics/angular             14.0.2
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.7.4
```

Note: [this is possibly a regression of the builder](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/issues/113)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay quoting @just-jeb from github

> It's mentioned in the [migration guide](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/blob/master/MIGRATION.MD#jest-builder). It's a breaking change of
> Angular CLI, not the builder. camelCase arguments are no longer
> supported.

Here is therefore the proper way to run the "MyComponent" test

```bash
ng test --test-name-pattern="MyComponent"
```

Note: [Jetbrains does not yet (28.06.2022) supports the kebab case arguments](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-56303)